# Kubuntu 20.04: How to change icons for GTK applications?

Tags: kubuntu, icons, themes, gtk

Hi everyone please I have a quite simple looking question.

I don't know how to change icons for GTK2/3 applications in Kubuntu 20.04. I looked on kde.org where is [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvlc8.png) from System Settings, but I can only change GTK theme in Kubuntu 20.04, there is no controls for icon themes.

For example Firefox and Thunderbird use Adwaita icons, but I don't see Adwaita settings anywhere in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`. Property `gtk-icon-theme-name` here in ini file doesn't seem to be respected.

Comment: If I were you, I would submit feedback to KDE and suggest that they add these options back. I believe it has to do with a different way that GTK is handled in KDE.  In the meantime, it seems to work to change the icon path in the `.desktop` files under `/usr/share/applications`.  If this works for you let me know and I'll compose an answer.

Comment: @Nmath: Thanks for quick reply. This seems to be only setup for application icon. What I meant is change icon theme used within GTK application (system menu, toolbars, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that some applications use their own themes and doesn't respect the system settings. I'll just have to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that GTK3 applications should inherit the icon theme you set in system settings, but GTK2 applications need a bit more configuration.

You need to edit the file at `~/.gtkrc-2.0`:

- First, make a backup:

  ```
  cd ~/
  cp .gtkrc-2.0 .gtkrc-2.0.bak
  ```
- Open `~/.gtkrc-2.0` for editing:

  ```
  nano .gtkrc-2.0
  ```
- Make changes to values as needed.  The value for GTK2 icon themes is `gtk-icon-theme-name=`.  If you wanted to change this to use the "Breeze" icon set, you would change the line to read:

  ```
  gtk-icon-theme-name="Breeze"
  ```

  The theme name needs to match exactly to an icon theme you already have installed (case-sensitive).  Note the use of quotation marks.
- Save <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> & Exit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- Settings should take effect the next time any GTK2 icons are called to load, or you can reboot the PC.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this settings. I found out that some applications, e.g. from Mozilla suite are using their own themes and icons.