# How to define a theme for specific application in kde plasma?

Tags: 20.04, kde, plasma

Just installed edraw and I have Breeze-dark theme as the global theme, but edraw looks like its not cooperating. Mostly showing white letters on white background. If I switch the global theme to just breeze, edraw looks just fine.

Is there a way I can make this application open with the Breeze theme while keeping the global theme dark?

[edraw-breeze-dark-theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w0nb.png)

Comment: Theme settings in KDE only affect Qt applications.  As of 20.04, I believe that GTK3 applications also inherit the Qt theme, but older GTK2 applications still need to have a theme set manually.  The config is at `~/.gtkrc-2.0`.  If the software doesn't use GTK or Qt, then it doesn't respond to themes at all. I'm pretty sure you can't set a theme on a per-application basis, but you might want to check out "Window Rules", because you can set quite a few application-specific settings.  Here's a similar answer on how to configure `~/.gtkrc-2.0`: https://askubuntu.com/a/1290959

Comment: Hmm, maybe this is worth pointing out to edraw themselves as a bug with kde dark theme?
I didn't see anything about colors, theme, or appearance in window settings unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

I use the following three variables:

```
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=lxqt
GTK_THEME=Default
```

Comment: No clue what GNOME and LXQT have to do with KDE, but it works in Kubuntu 22.04 :-)

Comment: Worked for me for OpenModelica Editor on Kubuntu dark theme. Would love some more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Giving the advice of Felix, I tried the following with amazing results:

[Packet Tracer without the fix:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtOgC.png)
Here the text below the router is barely visible.

[Packet Tracer with the fix:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXGL7.png)
The text is now visible, and the general theme is  consistent.

Here's what I did:

1. Locate the `*.desktop` file of the application. (In my case: `/usr/local/share/applications/cisco-pt.desktop`)
2. Make a copy of it and paste it in `~/.local/share/applications`
3. In the line where is `Exec=...` add what Felix said. Just before the regular command for executing the application.

So the final desktop entry would be something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME /opt/pt/packettracer %f
Name=Packet Tracer 8.0.0
Icon=/opt/pt/art/app.png
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=application/x-pkt;application/x-pka;application/x-pkz;
```

Comment: I don't know if its necessary to add `env` to the command, but if it is, it would be like this: `Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME /opt/pt/packettracer %f`